# Error On Call Java Class in Oracle Database

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a java class that shown in below :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package oracletree1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author oracle
 */
public class TREEUPDATER {

    int Levels;
    int NodeId;
    int ParentId;
    String FatherID;
    int ChildBed_new;
    int ChildBes_new;
    int ChildMande_new;
    int ChildBed_old;
    int ChildBes_old;
    int ChildMande_old;
    int ParentBed;
    int ParentBes;
    int ParentMande;
    String Script;
    String ValueState;
    String TreeState;

    public TREEUPDATER() throws SQLException {

    }

    public void updating(int levels, int NodeIds, int childBed_old, int childBes_old, int childMande_old) throws SQLException {
        this.ChildBed_old = childBed_old;
        this.ChildBes_old = childBes_old;
        this.ChildMande_old = childMande_old;
        this.Levels = levels;
        this.NodeId = NodeIds;
        String[] array;
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.12:1521:orcl", "tree1",
                    "oracle");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
            // stmt.executeUpdate("insert into test.java_test(id) values (21)");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from value" + "where nodeid = " + NodeId);
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from tree where id = " + NodeId);
            while (rs.next()) {
                this.FatherID = rs2.getNString("FatherID");
                this.ChildBed_new = rs2.getInt("bed");
                this.ChildBes_new = rs2.getInt("bes");
                this.ChildMande_new = rs2.getInt("mande");
                array = new String[100000];
                array = FatherID.split("_");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    ResultSet rs3 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * from tree" + "where id = " + array[i]);
                    this.ParentId = rs3.getInt("id");
                    this.ParentBed = rs3.getInt("bed");
                    this.ParentBes = rs3.getInt("bes");
                    this.ParentMande = rs3.getInt("mande");
                    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                    ParentBed = ChildBed_new - ChildBed_old;
                    ParentBes = ChildBes_new - ChildBes_old;
                    this.TreeState = rs2.getNString("state");
                    if (TreeState.equalsIgnoreCase("BED")) {
                        this.ParentMande = ParentBed - ParentBes;
                    } else {
                        this.ParentMande = ParentBes - ParentBed;
                    }

                    this.Script = ("update value set bed = bed + " + ParentBed + " and bes = bes + " + ParentBes + "and mande = mande + " + ParentMande
                            + "where id = " + ParentId);
                    stmt2.executeUpdate("" + Script);

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a main class , that show in below :

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package oracletree1;

import java.sql.SQLException;

```
/**
 *
 * @author oracle
 */
public class OracleTree1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        TREEUPDATER t = new TREEUPDATER();

    }

}
```

I was loaded these classes into oracle database 11gr2 and i want to use a trigger for running the updating() method . So i was creating a procedure like that :

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE4 
(
  LEVELS IN NUMBER  
, NODEID IN NUMBER  
, CHILDBED_OLD IN NUMBER  
, CHILDBES_OLD IN NUMBER  
, CHILDMANDE_OLD IN NUMBER  
) AS 
 LANGUAGE java name 'TREEUPDATER.updating(1,2,3,4,5)';
```

But when i want to compile and run this procedure , i have this error :

```
Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Error(9,16): PLS-00311: the declaration of "TREEUPDATER.updating(1,2,3,4,5)" is incomplete or malformed
```

Can any one solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: You better improve your English. Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Your code is a great candidate for SQL Injection.

Comment: this is a test code , do not worry about sql injection

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need a main function here, but it's not a big deal. In your case, you need to create a wrapper function (just a normal Oracle function invoking your java function). You can try this tutorial for a little help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1txuhyLGdH8

Hope this solves your problem :)